# Erlang nodes failed to connect

Tags: erlang

I'm writing a simple distributed Erlang system that allows nodes to pass messages among themselves. However some nodes connect to each other and other nodes refuse.  Starting Erlang I use `-name` flag, eg.

```
erl -name s@some.server.server
```

then in a different terminal start Erlang with

```
erl -name a@some.different.server
```

These two can talk just fine, but I create a third terminal and have that try to send messages it only lets me send messages to the first node, not the second.  Even `net_adm:ping` fails.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

is it in a different machine,

> For two nodes to communicate, not only must both of them be alive,
>   but also they must share some information contained in an atom called
>   the secret cookie. Each node has a single cookie value at any time,
>   and nodes sharing the same value can communicate. Each node can be
>   started with an explicit cookie value, as in the following: erl -sname
>   foo -setcookie blah If no value is set on launch, the Erlang runtime
>   system will pick up the value stored in the file .erlang.cookie. If
>   the file does not exist, it will be created in the home directory of
>   the user’s account.

use this

```
erl -name foo -setcookie blah
```

Answer (score 1):

You need set the right cookies.

> Authentication determines which nodes are allowed to communicate with
>   each other. In a network of different Erlang nodes, it is built into
>   the system at the lowest possible level. Each node has its own magic
>   cookie, which is an Erlang atom.
>
> When a nodes tries to connect to another node, the magic cookies are
>   compared. If they do not match, the connected node rejects the
>   connection.

please refer here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id85608