# Erlang nodes failed to connect each other

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, epmd

First. [Erlang nodes failed to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586961/erlang-nodes-failed-to-connect) and [Erlang - Nodes don't recognize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762894/erlang-nodes-dont-recognize) are useless.

I have tried all the ways.

It is ok for the same machine. But it failed between machines.

```
test@centos-1:~$ ping apple@centos-1 -c 1
PING apple@centos-1 (192.168.142.135) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from apple@centos-1 (192.168.142.135): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms

test@centos-1:~$ ping pear@centos-2 -c 1
PING pear@centos-2 (192.168.142.136) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from pear@centos-2 (192.168.142.136): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.292 ms
```

## apple@centos-1 starts

```
@centos-1:~$ erl -sname apple@centos_1 -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 6369 inet_dist_listen_max 7369 -setcookie CKYBWKWCWNLSPZWSLJXT
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

Eshell V12.2  (abort with ^G)
(apple@centos_1)1>
```

## pear@centos-2 starts

```
test@centos-2:~$ erl -sname pear@centos-2 -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 6369 inet_dist_listen_max 7369 -setcookie CKYBWKWCWNLSPZWSLJXT
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

Eshell V12.2  (abort with ^G)
(pear@centos-2)1>
```

## connection failed

```
test@centos-1:~$ erl -sname apple@centos_1 -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 6369 inet_dist_listen_max 7369 -setcookie CKYBWKWCWNLSPZWSLJXT
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

Eshell V12.2  (abort with ^G)
(apple@centos_1)1> net
net           net_adm       net_kernel
(apple@centos_1)1> net_kernel:connect_node('pear@centos-2').
false
(apple@centos_1)2>
```

## I have checked all the situations I have found

### The hosts file

```
192.168.142.135  apple@centos-1
192.168.142.136  pear@centos-2
```

### cookie

They have the same cookie.

### firewall

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=6000-8000/tcp --permanent
```

### tcpdump

There are not any package.

Comment: Primary communication is epmd TCP port 4369, it is used to discover the ports these processes choose within the ranges you are assigning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35769392/1269466 looks like the correct answer to me, it brings up port 4369 which is missing from the firewall-cmd.

Comment: I have checked,  It also does not work。@centos-2:~$ epmd  -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name orange at port 6369

Comment: I use -name other than -sname. Then it works.

Comment: these apple@ and pear@ names are supposed to be for erl services not part of your hosts configuration, the purpose of epmd is to answer look ups of ports for these names.. For sname to work /etc/resolv.conf should have the same domain in both hosts and centos-1.[domain name] has to really resolve to 192.168.142.135, etc..

Comment: OK. But  it 's not allowed to use  '-sname centos-1.[domain name].'   .     '-name centos-1.[domain name].'  is OK.

Comment: when you type -sname it is in erl, there you use an [service]@[host] where @host is optional. When you edit your hosts file there is no service there is only a host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is not responsible for service names, so this ping should fail:

`test@centos-1:~$ ping apple@centos-1 -c 1`

This linux ping should succeed:

`test@centos-1:~$ ping centos-1 -c 1`

Erlang examples are often using functions called ping/pong that would use epmd and use @ synax.

This looks good if domains are setup correctly (though note '-' and '_' are not the same):

`@centos-1:~$ erl -sname apple@centos-1 -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 6369 inet_dist_listen_max 7369 -setcookie CKYBWKWCWNLSPZWSLJXT Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]`

Hosts are just:

```
192.168.142.135  centos-1
192.168.142.136  centos-2
```

so the pear@centos-2 like lines you setup are not being used by erl. You can run as many erl shells as you like with different names and not need to update hosts.

Once that setup is working if you look in /etc/resolv.conf you should have a domain and it should be the same on both machines. If it is, you can try adding an alias with it to the hosts like this:

```
192.168.142.135  centos-1 centos-1.example.com
192.168.142.136  centos-2 centos-2.example.com
```

Though ideally the setup in resolv.conf is to a local dns server that set's this naming up so centos-1.example.com and centos-2.example.com can already ping each other.

Comment: Yes, Just like this, not with @： 192.168.142.135   centos-1